# check in JavaScript.. if path arrays and objects exist in object

Tags: javascript, lodash

UPDATE: is not duplicated with question about path of objects, my question is mix objects and arrays elements with [0] or [1] or more ..

I have this code to try to get the errors, there a different 'paths' for errors; sometimes  I need to change  the error message accord to the path where I found the error.

Is there a way in lodash or js to ask if exist a path of object and arrays; by example:

```
_includes(err., 'graphQLErrors[0].state[0].key')
```

here my actual code:

```
  try {
    errorMessage =  err.graphQLErrors[0].state[0].key; // general error message
  } catch (e) { /* ignore the error */ }
```

i've been seen anothers links and solutiosn, but nothing to mix array and elements mixing elements [nElement] and arrays '.'

Comment: See also [Accessing nested JavaScript objects with string key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6491463/218196) for how to convert a single string (`'graphQLErrors[0].state[0].key'`) to an array of properties.

Comment: duplicated maybe with the link on your comments, but not with 'javascript test for existence of nested object key' can you correct it ? i ll try your second option

Comment: FYI, arrays are objects. `0` is a property just like `state`. You'd use the solution of the accepted answer in the duplicate as `checkNested(err, 'graphQLErrors', 0, 'state', 0, 'key');`.

Comment: thanks the sample solutions is    https://lodash.com/docs#get  var object = { 'a': [{ 'b': { 'c': 3 } }] };
 
_.get(object, 'a[0].b.c');